# Angular - Mocha - Tests Fail when I add multiple Controllers to the same Module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocha.js, karma-mocha

When I have one controller attached to a module, I can use mocha, karma to test it successfully.  But when I add two controllers to the same module, the tests fail.  Why is that?

I have 2 controllers defined on the same module.  I can manually test the controllers and they work.

```
src/app/itemListController.js
angular.module('lazyLoad', [])
  .controller('ItemListController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
...
}]);

src/app/invoiceController.js
angular.module('lazyLoad', [])
  .controller('InvoiceController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
...
}]);
```

And 2 unit-tests:

```
test/app/itemListController.mocha.js
'use strict';
describe('testing movies', function () {
  var scope;
  var fixture;

  beforeEach(module('lazyLoad'));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    fixture =  $controller('ItemListController', {$scope: scope});
  }));

  it('....', function() {});
});

test/app/invoiceController.mocha.js
'use strict';
describe('testing movies', function () {
  var scope;
  var fixture;

  beforeEach(module('lazyLoad'));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    fixture =  $controller('InvoiceController', {$scope: scope});
  }));

  it('....', function() {});
});
```

I get:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) testing movies "before each" hook: workFn FAILED
    the object {
      "line": 1761
      "message": "[ng:areq] Argument 'ItemListController' is not a function, got undefined
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/ng/areq?p0=ItemListController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined"
      "name": "Error"
```

Now if I change the module-name for the invoiceController.js and invoiceController.mocha.js to say invoiceM then both tests work.

I must be doing something wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define your modules twice. When you use brackets `[]` to pass empty dependencies, you actually create a module and replace an old one if exists with the same name. What you need to do is:

```
// Create the module, maybe in a separate place.
angular.module('lazyLoad', []);

// Attach controllers to that module:
angular.module('lazyLoad') // HEY! SEE THIS? NO BRACKETS.
  .controller('ItemListController', ...);]

angular.module('lazyLoad') // HEY! SEE THIS? NO BRACKETS.
  .controller('InvoiceController' ...);
```

Comment: That worked great!  Thanks.  I also changed my karma config such that the file that registers the module gets loaded first.  files:['src/app/module.js,...]